# Same nginx default file works on one server, but not the other?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am trying to write a "catch all port 80 and force 443" for various different domains and sub-domains that we have. For this I am trying to use a wildcard like so:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.ourdomain.com www.*.ourdomain.com *.anotherdomain.com www.*.anotherdomain.com
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

This is written in `/etc/nginx/sites-availiable/default`

I am using the exact same snippet, on three servers, all running the same version of NGINX.

Output from `sudo nginx -v` is: `nginx version: nginx/1.11.5` on both servers

Two of them work with no problems, the other won't let me start NGINX at all. I get the following:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid server name or wildcard "www.*.ourdomain.com" on 0.0.0.0:80
```

Any clues on this one particular server is behaving differently than the others, or how I can get it back in line?

If you need any additional information please ask and I will edit the question.

Comment: Probably because that's not a valid wildcard.  Have you confirmed that the two server versions are identical?  Things change between versions, including what is/isn't supported.

Comment: I've written an answer that quotes the NGINX documentation on this.  In short: those wildcards you're trying to use are invalid - you'll have to resort to a regex match for those cases.  See the quoted documentation in my answer.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you very much. I will certain read this now and hopefully improve the config. Would you care to speculate why it works on one of the servers but not the other? I suspect this would be an interesting point for future readers

Comment: "Glitches" sounds like the proper answer in this case.  However, to my knowledge, NGINX has never permitted wildcards as those you were using - it's entirely possible one of your builds is using a weird/altered nginx that isn't reflected anywhere, but that's outside the purview of the question to determine why it worked or not.

Comment: Also keep in mind, 1.11.x has not been supported by NGINX for a *while* - they only support the latest stable and mainline branches, and 1.11.x is a couple years old (1.15.x is the current mainline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wildcard pattern in question (`www.*.ourdomain.com` being the pattern) is not considered valid in NGINX for a `server_name` directive value.  Why it worked on the one server to begin with is a mystery that I'll chalk up to 'glitches'.

To quote the [NGINX Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) on the `server_name` directive (the section is called "Server Names") which specifically relates to this case you've mentioned:

> **Wildcard names**
>
> A wildcard name may contain an asterisk only on the name’s start or
>   end, and only on a dot border. The names `www.*.example.org` and
>   `w*.example.org` are invalid. However, these names can be specified
>   using regular expressions, for example, `~^www\..+\.example\.org$` and
>   `~^w.*\.example\.org$`. An asterisk can match several name parts. The
>   name `*.example.org` matches not only `www.example.org` but
>   `www.sub.example.org` as well.
>
> A special wildcard name in the form `.example.org` can be used to
>   match both the exact name `example.org` and the wildcard name
>   `*.example.org`.

You will need to use regex-based detection matches for such domain/subdomain matches, per the documentation.

Comment: As per your answer "An asterisk can match several name parts. The name *.example.org matches not only www.example.org but  www.sub.example.org as wel"  - Would I be correct in assuming *.ourdomaindomain.com *.anotherdomain.com would work just fine for the use-case I put in my question?

Comment: @Aphire correct, because the asterisk is only at the beginning of the string match (and the wildcard asterisk position is based on each individual string being matched, not the entire `server_names` directive value entered).  However, that will not match the bare domain of just `ourdomaindomain.com` or `anotherdomain.com` - if you need *that* you may want to do it as `ourdomaindomain.com *.ourdomaindomain.com anotherdomain.com *.anotherdomain.com` or similar.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your time. I shall happily upvote and marked this as answered as soon as I can.